# Recieving data from SQLite database in a model object is being problematic

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-activity

I am creating Table of Administrators having different roles.
When a user signs up then the data,eg: Name,Email,Password,Role,Address gets saved in my ADMIN_TBL .There's no problem in this signup data being saved.

But when i try to fetch the same data , by giving a sql query clause(email=? and pass=? ) my **Administrator model object** is recieving null.

EDIT: Unable to recieve the data from database even though the table and data exixts.This is exactly the problem i am facing.

Here's the DBHelper class

```
package com.thebitshoes.uocn.DAO;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import com.thebitshoes.uocn.Model.Administrator;
import com.thebitshoes.uocn.Model.Student;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by thebitshoes on 11/2/17.
 */

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    static  final String DBNAME="UOCNDB";
    static final int VERSION=3;

    public static final String TBLName="student_table";
    public static final String ID="ID";
    public static final String NAME="name";
    public static final String AGE="age";
    public static final String GENDER="gender";
    public static final String COURSE="course";
    public static final String STD_EMAIL="email";
    public static final String STUDENT_CONTACT="student_contact";
    public static final String PARENTS_CONTACT="parents_contact";
    public static final String PARENTS_FULLNAME="parents_fullname";

    public static final String ADMIN_TBL="admin_table";
    public static final String ROLE="role";
    public static final String TEACHING_STATUS="status";
    public static final String ADMIN_MAIL="emailid";
    public static final String ADMIN_CONTACT="contact";
    public static final String ADMIN_PASS="password";
    public static final String ADMIN_ADDRESS="address";

    public static final String COURSE_TBL="course_table";
    public static final String COURSE_TITLE="course_title";
    public static final String COURSE_DURATION="course_duration";

    public static final String FEEDBACK_TBL="feedback_table";
    public static final String FEEDBACK="feedback";
    public static final String FEED_STATUS="feed_status";
    public static final String FEED_DATE="feed_date";


    public static final String ATTENDANCE_TBL="attendance_tbl";
    public static final String START_DATE="start_date";
    public static final String END_DATE="end_date";
    public static final String LEAVE="leave";
    public static final String ABSENT="absent";

    public static final String ROUTINE_TBL="routine_table";
    public static final String SUBJECT="subject";
    public static final String ROUTINE_DATE_TIME="routine_date_time";

    public static final String REPLY_MASTER="reply_master_table";
    public static final String USER_EMAIL="emailid";
    public static final String REPLY_MESSAGE="reply_msg";
    public static final String REPLY_STATUS="reply_status";
    public static final String REPLY_DATE="reply_date";




    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String query="create table "+TBLName+" ( "+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+
                NAME+" TEXT, "+AGE+" TEXT, "+GENDER+" TEXT, "+
                COURSE+" TEXT, "+STD_EMAIL+" TEXT, "+STUDENT_CONTACT+" TEXT, "+
                PARENTS_CONTACT+" TEXT, "+PARENTS_FULLNAME+" TEXT)";

        String admin_query="create table "+ADMIN_TBL+" ( "+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+NAME+
                " TEXT, "+ADMIN_MAIL+
                " TEXT, "+ADMIN_CONTACT+" TEXT, "+
                ADMIN_PASS+" TEXT, "+ADMIN_ADDRESS+" TEXT, "+
                ROLE+" TEXT, "+
                TEACHING_STATUS+" TEXT)";
        String routine_query="create table "+ROUTINE_TBL+" ( "+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+
                COURSE+" TEXT, "+SUBJECT+" TEXT, "+ROUTINE_DATE_TIME+
                " TEXT)";
        String reply_query="create table "+REPLY_MASTER+" ( "+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+
                USER_EMAIL+" TEXT, "+REPLY_MESSAGE+" TEXT, "+
                REPLY_STATUS+" TEXT, "+REPLY_DATE+" TEXT)";
        String attendance_query="create table "+ATTENDANCE_TBL+" ( "+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+ START_DATE+" TEXT, "+END_DATE+ " TEXT, "+LEAVE+" TEXT, "+ABSENT+" TEXT)";

        String feedback_query="creeate table "+FEEDBACK_TBL+" ( "+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+ USER_EMAIL+" TEXT, "+FEEDBACK+" TEXT, "+FEED_STATUS+" TEXT, "+FEED_DATE+" TEXT)";

        String course_query="create table "+COURSE_TBL+" ( "+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+
                COURSE_TITLE+" TEXT, "+COURSE_DURATION+
                " TEXT)";

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(admin_query);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(routine_query);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(reply_query);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(attendance_query);
       sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(feedback_query);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(course_query);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        //onUpgrade remove the existing table, and recreate and populate new data
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TBLName);
        onCreate(db);

    }

/*    public static final String ADMIN_TBL="admin_table";
    public static final String ROLE="role";
    public static final String TEACHING_STATUS="status";
    public static final String ADMIN_MAIL="emailid";
    public static final String ADMIN_CONTACT="contact";
    public static final String ADMIN_PASS="password";
    public static final String ADMIN_ADDRESS="address";*/




// ADDING DATA TO DATABASE

    public long addAdminUsers(Administrator obj){
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

        cv.put(NAME,obj.getName());
        cv.put(ADMIN_MAIL,obj.getPassword());
        cv.put(ADMIN_CONTACT,obj.getContact());
        cv.put(ADMIN_PASS,obj.getPassword());
        cv.put(ADMIN_ADDRESS,obj.getAddress());
        cv.put(ROLE,obj.getRole());
        cv.put(TEACHING_STATUS,obj.getTeachingStatus());
        long l2=db.insert(ADMIN_TBL,null,cv);
        return l2;

    }

    public long addStudents(Student obj){
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

        cv.put(NAME,obj.getName());
        cv.put(AGE,obj.getAge());
        cv.put(GENDER,obj.getGender());
        cv.put(COURSE,obj.getCourseOpted());
        cv.put(STD_EMAIL,obj.getStudentEmail());
        cv.put(STUDENT_CONTACT,obj.getStudentContact());
        cv.put(PARENTS_CONTACT,obj.getParentsContact());
        cv.put(PARENTS_FULLNAME,obj.getParentsFullName());
        long insert=db.insert(TBLName,null,cv);
        return insert;
    }



//Recieveing data based on EMAIL and PASSWORD     


    public Administrator getAdminByEmailPassRole(String email,String pass){
        SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
        String q="select * from "+ADMIN_TBL+" where "+ADMIN_MAIL+" =? and "+ADMIN_PASS+" =?";
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(q,new String[]{email,pass});
        Administrator obj=null;

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            obj=new Administrator();
            obj.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            obj.setEmailId(cursor.getString(2));
            obj.setContact(cursor.getString(3));
            obj.setPassword(cursor.getString(4));
            obj.setAddress(cursor.getString(5));
            obj.setRole(cursor.getString(6));
            obj.setTeachingStatus(cursor.getString(7));
        }
        return obj;


    }

}
```

**Here's the Activity class from which the user can LOGIN/SIGNUP(LandingPage)**

```
package com.thebitshoes.uocn;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.thebitshoes.uocn.DAO.DBHelper;
import com.thebitshoes.uocn.Model.Administrator;

public class LandingPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    DBHelper db;
    String role;

    String[]roles={
            "--select role--","Student","Teacher","Parent","Admin",
    };
    Spinner role_spinner;

    EditText lib_email,lib_pass;
    TextView lib_signUp;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_landing_page);
        lib_email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lib_emailId);
        lib_pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lib_pass);
        db=new DBHelper(this);


        lib_signUp=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lib_signup_tv);
        role_spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.role_spinner_widget);
        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,roles);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        role_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        role_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                switch(i){
                    case 0:
                        break;
                    case 1: role="Student";
                        break;
                    case 2: role="Teacher";
                        break;
                    case 3: role="Parent";
                        break;
                    case 4: role="Admin";
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });

        lib_signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LandingPage.this,AdminSignUp.class));
            }
        });

    }

    public void loginNow(View v){
        String email=lib_email.getText().toString();
        String pass=lib_pass.getText().toString();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," E :"+email+" P: "+pass,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Administrator obj=db.getAdminByEmailPassRole(email,pass);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+obj.getName()+" "+obj.getRole()+obj.getContact(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

**The signup page which adds user info to database(AdminSignup)**

```
package com.thebitshoes.uocn;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.thebitshoes.uocn.DAO.DBHelper;
import com.thebitshoes.uocn.Model.Administrator;

public class AdminSignUp extends AppCompatActivity {
    String role;
    LinearLayout child_detail_layout,basic_detail_layout;
    Button signup;


    String[]roles={
            "--select a role--","Teacher","Parent","Admin",
    };
    Spinner role_spinner;

    EditText nameofChild,name_tv,email_tv,password_tv,contact_tv,address_tv;
    Administrator admin_obj;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_sign_up);
        setTitle("User Sign Up");
        child_detail_layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.child_detail_layout);
        basic_detail_layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.basic_detail_layout);
        signup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.admin_signup);
        role="";

        name_tv=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.admin_name_tv);
        email_tv=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.admin_mail_tv);
        password_tv=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.admin_pass_tv);
        contact_tv=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.admin_contact_tv);
        address_tv=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.address_tv);




        role_spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.admin_role_spin);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,roles);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        role_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        role_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                switch(i){
                    case 0:
                        role="";
                        break;
                    case 1: role="Teacher";
                        child_detail_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        basic_detail_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        signup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case 2: role="Parent";
                        basic_detail_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        child_detail_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        signup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        break;
                    case 3: role="Admin";
                        child_detail_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        basic_detail_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        signup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });

    }

    public void signupAdmin(View v){
        long check=0;
        admin_obj=new Administrator();
        DBHelper db=new DBHelper(this);
        String n,e,p,c,ad;
        n=name_tv.getText().toString();
        e=email_tv.getText().toString();
        p=password_tv.getText().toString();
        c=contact_tv.getText().toString();
        ad=address_tv.getText().toString();

        if(n.equalsIgnoreCase("")||e.equalsIgnoreCase("")||p.equalsIgnoreCase("")||c.equalsIgnoreCase("")||ad.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"All fields are mandatory",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            admin_obj.setName(n);
            admin_obj.setEmailId(e);
            admin_obj.setPassword(p);
            admin_obj.setContact(c);
            admin_obj.setRole(role);
            admin_obj.setAddress(ad);
            admin_obj.setTeachingStatus("Active");
            check=db.addAdminUsers(admin_obj);
            if(check>0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfully Created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(this,LandingPage.class));
            }
            else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



    }
}
```

**Here's the error LOG**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.thebitshoes.uocn, PID: 26277
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.thebitshoes.uocn.Model.Administrator.getName()' on a null object reference
                      at com.thebitshoes.uocn.LandingPage.loginNow(LandingPage.java:84)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Your Administrator object is null

Comment: `at com.thebitshoes.uocn.LandingPage.loginNow(LandingPage.java:84)` This says the error is on line 84 of LandingPage.java. Start there.

Comment: I am trying to recieve data in the Administrator object at line 83(LandingPage.java).  Administrator obj=db.getAdminByEmailPassRole(email,pass);  Why i am not getting the data here? How is it null. The data exixts in table though

Comment: @ThePercept log something in if part @ `if(cursor.moveToFirst())` and check.

Comment: @Raghunandan Why my object is not recieving any data from the db at line 83 ? I am trying to get the data from db by passing email and password as argument

Comment: inline `this = {DBHelper@4346} 
email = "nishant@gmail.com"
pass = "12345"
db = {SQLiteDatabase@4351} "SQLiteDatabase: /data/user/0/com.thebitshoes.uocn/databases/UOCNDB"
q = "select * from admin_table where emailid =? and password =?"
cursor = {SQLiteCursor@4353} 
obj = null`

Comment: @Raghunandan i clicked on the line and debugger shows the above message [Heres's the screenshot](http://i64.tinypic.com/2qcmtqq.png)

Comment: @ThePercept obj = null you can see that. Check your query

Comment: @sajan please explain your answer

Comment: Either there is no data in the database with that email and password or your query is not structured appropriately. Confirm that data exists in the database using some tool like this -> http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: i am using the same table from the same database to retrieve data for the different role , by using where ROLE =? clause to populate a list view. The list shows me the data for TEACHERS,PARENTS,ADMIN,STUDENTS of the same email and pass. Considering i have the data in database , how to make sure that my query is structured here?

Comment: What can be wrong with the query structure? It seems fine i guess

Comment: I finally found the stupid mistake in DBHelper file . I was doing this `cv.put(ADMIN_MAIL,obj.getPassword());` instead of this         `cv.put(ADMIN_MAIL,obj.getEmailId());`